# Meteor iron:router data

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Do you now if i can use $myVar in all route data ?

Example :

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('posts'),
            Meteor.subscribe('skills'),
            Meteor.subscribe('tasks'),
            Meteor.subscribe('profil')
        ];
    },
    data: function() {

        var myVar = Profil.findOne({},{
            sort: {
                createdAt: 1
            }, limit: 1
        });

    }
});
```

And use myVar on this data :

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    data: function(){

        var posts = Posts.find();

        return {
            posts: posts
        };

    },
    onAfterAction: function() {

        SEO.set({
            title: test.seoSuffix,
            meta: {
                'description': 'une description'
            }
        });

    }
});
```

I would like use test.xxx on all route if i need it. But this code don't work.

Thank you !

Comment: (a) I'm not sure why you want to nest the cursor in an object. `return posts` would work fine. (b) in your first example `myVar` isn't returned anywhere, it's just dead code. `var` sets the scope to the enclosing function and that's as far as it goes.

Comment: I've remove `var`, and it work ! Thank you :)

Comment: That means you've made `myVar` a _global_ variable.